# Where Core Data is saving?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I use this code to initialize Core Data:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreData

class DataController: NSObject {
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override init() {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Highlightings")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

How can I specify a *.sqlite* file where Core Data should save data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **could** go back to the older approach without `NSPersistentContainer`. The old API has not been deprecated.

If you're using `NSPersistentContainer`, you can change the store location using `NSPersistentStoreDescription`. Something like

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ContinerName")

let storeURL = // Initialize to whatever URL you want
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)

container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [ description ]

container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: With the new approach the .sqlite file is located in ~/Library/Application Support/YOURAPPNAME/